# '/bin/sh: go: not found' in 'docker:dind' container

Tags: docker, go, docker-container, docker-in-docker

I try to install `Golang` (go1.13.9.linux-amd64) in docker-in-docker container(`docker:dind`) manually (copy `go` binaries to a container).

`Go` was copied to `/go/bin`,

```
/ # export GOROOT=/go
/ # export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
/ # 
/ # uname -a
Linux 41868f6e7ae3 4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue May 26 11:42:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux
/ #
/ # echo $GOROOT
/go
/ #
/ # echo $PATH
/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I try check version and get an error:

```
/ # go version
/bin/sh: go: not found
```

I try add `env` to `/etc/profile`  the same error.

Comment: I have no knowledge of DinD, but would it not be easier to use the GoLang official images instead? --> https://hub.docker.com/_/golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention the base image, but better to use on the of the base image either for `go` or `docker-dind`, I will recommend `dind` that is base on alpine and then install `go`.

```
FROM docker:dind
RUN apk add --no-cache go
RUN go version
```

output

```
Step 3/3 : RUN go version
 ---> Running in 123401c3ebad
go version go1.12.12 linux/amd64
```

Comment: @Adiii-thx, why have I get this error when try install `go` bin?

Comment: @Adiii-copy go binaries into container and set `env` (`$GOROOT` and `$PATH`)

Comment: I see, Alpine package is available so I think that's he best option